# Why the code innerHTML on javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

there are HTML code and JavaScript code

```
<script>
   function Stock_Listing() {
      document.getElementById("stock_menu").innerHTML = "hi";
   }
</script>

<ul id="stock_menu" onload="Stock_Listing()"></ul>
```

but there is nothing on my page.

could you plz tell me why is not working?

and also not working insertAdjacentHTML.

```
<script>
    function Stock_Listing() {
       document.getElementById("stock_menu").insertAdjacentHTML = ("afterbegin", "hi");
    }
</script>

<ul id="stock_menu" onload="Stock_Listing()"></ul>
```

Comment: You’re not calling the `Stock_Listing` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onLoad` function, you are declaring a function but never calling it. You don't need that second function:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("stock_menu").innerHTML = "hi";
}
```

```html
    <ul id="stock_menu"></ul>
```

Or at least, you need to call that second function:

```js
   window.onload = function() {
      function Stock_Listing() {
         document.getElementById("stock_menu").innerHTML = "hi";
      }
      
      Stock_Listing();
   }
```

```html
<ul id="stock_menu"></ul>
```

Both method works, I would prefer the first one since you don't really need the `Stock_Listing` function.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the second function, Stock_Listing(), anywhere. You need to call it or take the get element.... line outside of it